# SQLite Check Constraints and SQLite DB Browser

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I am using SQLite DB Browser v3.7.0.  If I create a table using the following syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE "A" (
    "AREA" TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT 'DEFAULT'
        CONSTRAINT "A-AREA-MAX_LENGTH_CHECK"
            CHECK(LENGTH("AREA") <= 25),
    CONSTRAINT "A-AREA-UPPERCASE_NO_WHITESPACE_CHECK"
        CHECK(UPPER("AREA") = "AREA" AND INSTR("AREA", ' ') = 0)
);
```

When I go to the "Browse Data" tab of SQLite browser, I get no columns showing up (as if the browser is unable to parse the SQL).  This is a problem, since when I click "New Record", I get the exception "*Error adding record: near 
")": syntax error (INSERT INTO '' VALUES ();)*".

[image: SQLite DB Browser 3.7.0 Error]

However, if I change the constraint to be either one of:

```
CHECK(UPPER("AREA") = "AREA")
CHECK(INSTR("AREA", ' ') = 0)
```

Then SQLite DB Browser appears to parse everything correctly.  My question is, is the syntax above invalid SQLite, or is this an issue that needs to be reported to the SQLite DB Browser team?  Thanks.

**EDIT**

I also tested in SQLite DB Browser v3.8.0, with similar results:

[image: SQLite DB Browser 3.8.0 Error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is related to [issue #505: Sqlite parse error on CHECK constraint](https://github.com/sqlitebrowser/sqlitebrowser/issues/505), which was fixed on January 18.  I downloaded the April 3 [nightly build](http://rp.oldsch00l.com/sqlitebrowser/sqlitebrowser.exe.zip) of SQLite DB Browser (v3.8.99), and verified everything works as expected in that version.

Answer (score 1):

That's a bug with the interface. Running this code in SQLite version 3.8.2 generates the table correctly

```
sqlite> CREATE TABLE "A" (
    "AREA" TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT 'DEFAULT'
        CONSTRAINT "A-AREA-MAX_LENGTH_CHECK"
            CHECK(LENGTH("AREA") <= 25),
    CONSTRAINT "A-AREA-UPPERCASE_NO_WHITESPACE_CHECK"
        CHECK(UPPER("AREA") = "AREA" AND INSTR("AREA", ' ') = 0)
);

sqlite> .schema A
CREATE TABLE "A" (
    "AREA" TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT 'DEFAULT'
        CONSTRAINT "A-AREA-MAX_LENGTH_CHECK"
            CHECK(LENGTH("AREA") <= 25),
    CONSTRAINT "A-AREA-UPPERCASE_NO_WHITESPACE_CHECK"
        CHECK(UPPER("AREA") = "AREA" AND INSTR("AREA", ' ') = 0)
);
```

Edit: the constraints also work as intended:

```
sqlite> insert into A values ("area");
Error: CHECK constraint failed: A-AREA-UPPERCASE_NO_WHITESPACE_CHECK
sqlite> insert into A values ("AR EA");
Error: CHECK constraint failed: A-AREA-UPPERCASE_NO_WHITESPACE_CHECK
sqlite> insert into A values ("AREA");
sqlite> select * from A;
AREA
```